# VueJS directive similar to v-if fails unit tests (with vue-test-utils)

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-directives

I'm trying to create a directive that has behaviour similar to `v-if`. Basically if the condition is true, the element should exist, if it's false, it shouldn't. I also need to ensure that those changes pass JEST tests. The purpose is to create a permissions plugin (so I don't need to use `v-if="$isAllowed('edit', 'comments')"` syntax)

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003976/a-custom-directive-similar-to-v-if-in-vuejs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53897909/simulate-v-if-directive-in-custom-directive) tickets. The directive works, as in it replaces the element with a comment in the rendered DOM, however when running tests, the element still exists.

the directive:

```
Vue.directive('allow', (el, binding, vnode) => {
  if (!isAllowed(binding.value)) {
    const comment = document.createComment(' ');
    Object.defineProperty(comment, 'setAttribute', {
      value: () => undefined,
    });
    vnode.elm = comment;
    vnode.text = ' ';
    vnode.isComment = true;
    vnode.context = undefined;
    vnode.tag = undefined;
    vnode.data.directives = undefined;

    if (vnode.componentInstance) {
      vnode.componentInstance.$el = comment;
    }

    if (el.parentNode) {
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, el);
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```html
...
<div v-allow="['edit', 'comments']" test-name="comment">
   <!-- some irrelevant code here -->
</div>
...
```

The test:

```
it('does not render element when user has no access to it', () => {
   expect(wrapper.find('[test-name="comment"]').exists()).toBeFalsy();
});
```

The test fails (saying component exists). However, when I print the rendered html (`console.log(wrapper.html());`), it prints comment instead of the component.